# Calculating age in Teradara

Tags: date, datetime, teradata

I've got this to calculate age of a person in Teradata:

select  (extract(year from current_date) - extract(year from BIRTH_DATE) (named YEARS)) +   case when current_date - (YEARS (interval year)) < BIRTH_DATE then -1 else 0 end

However, all birth dates are in decimal, for instance, 17.773824. how can I covert this to the proper date and from it extract the years like in the code above? Do SQL functions like CONVERT work?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What date is 17.773824 supposed to be? How it's calculated?

Comment: Hi dnoeth, 17.773824 is a decimal. And it is supposed to be calculated by subtracting one's birthday from current (system) time. I was able to pull out a solution for it yesterday: "select cast(cast((birth_date_dim_ck - 19000000) as int) as date) as DOB,
  (current_date - DOB) year as Age". Apparently the 19000000 is how Teradata stores dates internally and we must use "as int" to convert the value to an integer since Teradata seems to no digest decimals in this case very well. Thanks a lot.

Comment: If you have found a working solution then please post it as an answer and accept that answer as the correct one. This may help others seeking help on similar issues.

Comment: You're right, xenodevil! I'll drop my solution right below. It also takes into account the month and the day, namely, it precisely calculates your age. It might be long and ugly, but it works :)

Comment: cast(cast((birth_date - 19000000) as int)as date) as DOB,
        extract (year from  current_date) - extract (year from  DOB ) + case when  extract (month from current_date) < extract (month from DOB)  then  -1 when extract (month from current_date) = extract (month from DOB) then  case when extract (day from current_date) < extract (day from  DOB) then  -1 else 0 end else 0 end as Age

Answer (score 4):

Here's a slightly different method.

```
select
cast((cast(date as int) - cast(BIRTH_DATE as int))/ 10000 as int) as AGE
```

Comment: this worked for me but I had to double cast a date entered manually, e.g. cast(cast('2021-07-31' as date) as int)